# Cuando quiero importar la librería tkinter me dice 'module' object is not callable y no se que hacer

Tags: tkinter, modulos, python-3.9

```
`import tkinter as Tk`
```

```
vn=Tk()
vn.geometry("400x300")
vn.mainloop
```

1. y me da este error import tkinter as Tk: File "c:\Users\iadpb\OneDrive\Escritorio\Pyhton\tkinter.py", line 1, in 
   import tkinter as Tk
   File "c:\Users\iadpb\OneDrive\Escritorio\Pyhton\tkinter.py", line 3, in 
   vn=Tk()
   TypeError: 'module' object is not callab

Answer (score 0):

Estás importando una librería y le estás cambiando el nombre a `Tk` lo cual no hace que al ejecutar `vn = Tk()` se esté ejecutando lo que crees que se está ejecutando.

`Tk` es un método interno y debe ser llamado como tal y dado que `Tk` ahora mismo es nombre que le has asignado al módulo importado, deberás ejecutarlo así:

```
vn = Tk.Tk()
```

Comment: aún me sigue dando el error

Comment: Cambia el nombre de tu archivo a algo diferente a `tkinter.py`. Puede estar intentando importar este mismo archivo y no funcionar debidamente por ello.

Comment: ya lo hice y nada